# proguard doesnt ignore referenced libraries

Tags: android, proguard

I use proguard, in proguard-project.txt, I have line for  ignoring referenced classes

-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

The log says:

> Warning: com.flurry.android.ab: can't find referenced class com.google.ads.InterstitialAd
>   Warning: com.flurry.android.ab: can't find referenced class com.google.ads.InterstitialAd
>   Warning: com.flurry.android.ab: can't find referenced class com.google.ads.InterstitialAd
>   Warning: com.flurry.android.ab: can't find referenced class com.google.ads.AdRequest
>   Warning: com.flurry.android.ab: can't find referenced class com.google.ads.AdRequest
>
> ..........
>
> You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>   Warning: there were 277 unresolved references to classes or
>   interfaces. You may need to
>   specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').  java.io.IOException: Please correct the above
>   warnings first. at
>   proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321) at
>   proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211) at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86) 
>   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)

I included line -libraryjars ./libs/FlurryAgent.jar to congig file. What is my problem?

Comment: Just try to add the `-dontwarn` tag in your proguard file then test.

Comment: Just remove `-libraryjars ./libs/FlurryAgent.jar` line from your config file and add `-dontwarn` tag in your file. If you add `-dontwarn` tag then remove this line `-dontwarn com.google.ads.**`.

Comment: in proguard-project.txt I left a sing line -dontwarn and still the same problem

Comment: Dear @Paul the proguard file name should be always having name like `proguard.cfg` not `proguard-project.txt`. Please change the name of the file by `proguard.cfg` and then try to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have tried, you should put this single line in `proguard-project.txt`:

```
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
```

You do have to make sure that ProGuard is actually using this configuration file, with this line in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

This is the standard line for Android SDK r20 or higher (older versions used just `proguard.config=proguard.cfg`, in which case you had to specify the entire configuration, instead of relying on the one in the SDK).

Answer (score 2):

Just add these lines to your proguard-android.txt.

```
# Flurry SDK support
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn com.inmobi.androidsdk.**
-dontwarn com.jumptap.adtag.**
-dontwarn com.millennialmedia.android.**
-dontwarn com.mobclix.android.sdk.**
-dontwarn com.flurry.android.monolithic.sdk.**
```